# Error: Unexpected any. Specify a different type. (Typescript Dispatch)

Tags: typescript, redux, types, react-redux, redux-thunk

I can't have `any` as a type in my code and so where `Dispatch<any>`, I get an error saying: Unexpected any. Specify a different type.

When I put `<unknown>` just to see if it will stop erroring, I get: Type 'unknown' does not satisfy the constraint 'Action'.

Does anyone know what's the type that goes with Dispatch?

```
export function doSomething(options: doSomethingOptions): ActionCreator<AnyAction> {
  return (dispatch: Dispatch<any>): Action => {
    ............
  };
}
```

Comment: It comes from redux--> import { Action, Dispatch, AnyAction, ActionCreator } from 'redux';

Comment: Yeah I added them, thanks

Comment: Separately, the `@types` package has [type definitions for various Redux packages](https://www.typescriptlang.org/dt/search?search=redux), have you installed any of them?

Comment: I see @types/redux-mock-store in my package.json but that's all and it seems unrelated

Comment: I think the type is the type of thing you want to dispatch, but again, I don't use it. [This](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/static-typing) may be helpful. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct type you are looking for is `Dispatch<AnyAction>`.

Also, having some `any`s in your codebase is generally fine. Here is a [blog article by a redux maintainer](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2019/11/blogged-answers-learning-and-using-typescript/#pragmatism-is-vital) on the topic.

If you have lint messages that hinder you from actually delivering value, you should talk to your team if you really want to keep them - and if your team insists on keeping them, they should provide you with the guidance to learn the required types. Maybe regular pair programming?

Comment: Hey, that seems to fix the issue in the code but in my test I get another error: Argument of type 'ActionCreator<AnyAction>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'.
  Property 'type' is missing in type 'ActionCreator<AnyAction>' but required in type 'AnyAction'.    Any ideas?

Comment: You need to correctly type your `dispatch` function, by default it does not accept thunks.
If you are using redux toolkit, you can just use the type of `store.dispatch` which is already typed correctly for all applied middlewares, otherwise you need to use `ThunkDispatch<any, any ,AnyAction>`, from the back of my head.